# Transforming lines of a csv file into objects

Tags: python, csv, oop

I am new to python and want to create a virtuel flashcard box (so you get questions and if you answer them right they get to the next box) I imported a csv file with a contant like this:

```
How many months has a year?        12               1
What is the highest mountain?      Mount Everest    1
...                                ...              ...
```

The first column contains the question, the second the solution and the third the number of the box in which the flashcard is. I want to transform the lines into objects and my approach goes like this:

```
while open ("myfile.csv", "r") as data:
    class flashcard:
        def __init__(self, question, solution, number):
            self.question = question
            self.solution = solution
            self.number = number
        for line in data:
            q, s, n = line.strip().split(",")
            NAME = flashcard(q, s, n)
```

The problem is that I think that I am not able to create names in a loop so that the last line of the code won't work. What can I do to solve this? It looks like a problem many people have but I couldn't find anything about it on google.

Comment: if `flashcard` is supposed to represent one question, it would be good to not let it access `data`. You could create a list and append it instances of flashcards.

Comment: You seem to be trying to create `flashcard`s from within the definition of `flashcard`; is that your intent?

Comment: You need to define your class globally, and then create *instances* of that class. Also, it is convention to capitalize class names in Python. E.g., your class should be called `Flashcard`.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop shouldn't contain the class definition. Unless you have very good reasons not to, class definitions should be in global scope. Try the following.

```py
class Flashcard:
    def __init__(self, question, solution, number):
        self.question = question
        self.solution = solution
        self.number = number

while open ("myfile.csv", "r") as data:
    for line in data:
        q, s, n = line.strip().split(",")
        NAME = Flashcard(q, s, n)
```

**Note:** I'd recommend using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) instead of doing your own parsing.

Answer (score 0):

For csv data, you should use Python's `csv` module. Note that I've changed your `Flashcard` class to use a capitalized name, as is convention in Python. Also, I don't really know what your intention is, so I'm just putting instances of `Flashcard` in a `list`.

```py
import csv


class Flashcard:
    def __init__(self, question, solution, number):
        self.question = question
        self.solution = solution
        self.number = number


list_of_flashcards = []
with open("myfile.csv", newline="") as flashcard_data:
    for line in csv.reader(flashcard_data, delimiter=","):
        question, solution, number = line
        list_of_flashcards.append(Flashcard(question, solution, number))
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending @blorgon's answer you can use a dictionary to store the Flashcard objects so that the search can be fast. The `reader.line_num` is used to create a key for each line and store the respective Flashcard instance object.

```
import csv

class Flashcard:
    def __init__(self, question, solution, number):
        self.question = question
        self.solution = solution
        self.number = number

list_of_flashcards = {}
with open("myfile.csv", newline="") as flashcard_data:
    reader = csv.reader(flashcard_data, delimiter=",")
    for line in reader:
        q, s, n = list(map(str.strip,line))
        list_of_flashcards["NAME{}".format(reader.line_num)]=Flashcard(q, s, n)
```